# gtable (from R package gWidgets2) returns previous selection

Tags: r, gwidgets

The gtable widget from the gWidgets2 package in R returns the previously selected value when clicking on a new value. If using the keyboard arrows to select a value and then Enter to activate the current selection is returned. This was unexpected behaviour for me. If this is how it should work by design, how can I get the current selection in both cases?

**EDIT:** It seems like it works as expected using gWidgets, so it might be a bug in gWidgets2. Start a new R session and change to gWidgets2 -> gWidgets and gvbox -> ggroup in the example below.

```
require(gWidgets2)

# Select by clicking (Clicked) or hit Enter (Changed)
# Move using mouse or arrow keys.

# Create the example (adopted from the gtable example)
w <- gwindow("gtable example", visible=FALSE)
g <- gvbox(cont=w)
tbl <- gtable(mtcars, cont=g, expand=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

addHandlerClicked(tbl, handler = function(h, ...) {

  print("Clicked returns the previously selected value.")

  print(svalue(tbl))

} )

addHandlerChanged(tbl, handler = function(h, ...) {

  print("Changed returns the currently selected value.")

  print(svalue(tbl))

} )

visible(w) <- TRUE
```

*R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
Packages: gWidgets2_1.0-7, gWidgets2RGtk2_1.0-6, RGtk2_2.20.33*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @jverzani on GitHub https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/issues/94#issuecomment-316739581

> Sorry, I don't have a good solution here. I thought I did, but can't
>   figure it out. The issue is the gWidgets2 observer is called before
>   the widget is updated. I thought staging the handlers differently
>   would work, but ...
>
> The workaround would be to not connect this way, but rather use
>   `addHandlerSelectionChanged` This gives single click and keyboard
>   response, but doesn't play nicely with double click. Alternatively,
>   double click is supposed to "activate" the cell initiating a callback,
>   so not assigning to the click handler is possible and just assigning
>   to the change handler gives you double click and keyboard selection,
>   but not single click, which just sets the selection but doesn't
>   initiate a callback.

It seem to work as expected in my application. I use only `addHandlerChanged` in one place and only `addHandlerSelectionChanged` in another.